# How go's map hash function workes so different type with "same" value result in different key?

Tags: dictionary, go, hashmap

I know the value is **not same** so I double qouted it, what I want to know is how go's map hash works so that `cusKey` and `a` is different in type result in the key is different.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type key int

const cusKey key = 1
const a int = 1


func main() {
    dic := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
    dic[cusKey] = 5
    dic[a] = 6
    fmt.Println(dic[cusKey])
    fmt.Println(dic[a])
}
```

the output is

```
5
6
```

How go achieve this? The two keys value are all `1`.

I know in go if the type is different, two value is different. So the two `1` is not identical.

But how actually go's map did it? I tried to find out at `map.go` in source, but I can't found where go implement the hash funcion. Is it calculates hash of the keys with type annotations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`a` and `cusKey` cannot be equal because they have different types. `a` is of type `int`, and `cusKey` is of type `key` (which has `int` as its underlying type, but it is a different type).

Go maps require keys to be comparable. [Spec: Map types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)

> The [comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) `==` and `!=` must be fully defined for operands of the key type

The key type of your `dic` map is `interface{}`, it's an interface type, and interface values are comparable if [Spec: Comparison operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)

> - Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value `nil`.

An interface value stores the dynamic type and value, schematically, it's a  "(value, type)" pair. When interface values are compared, the type is compared too, and if they don't match, the interface value comparison will yield `false`. For details about interface representation, see [Go Data Structures: Interfaces (by Russ Cox)](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces).

For internals about Go's map, check out [Dave Cheney: How the Go runtime implements maps efficiently (without generics)](https://dave.cheney.net/2018/05/29/how-the-go-runtime-implements-maps-efficiently-without-generics).

Comment: So map's hash function will use the "(value, type)" pair when calculate hash for a `interface{}`, thus they are different keys in a look up operation?

Comment: @LiJinyao Yes. Added a link which writes about Go's map implementation, check that out.

Comment: j@LiJinyao Somehow my edit disappeared, (re-)added the link now.

Comment: Thanks! That link helps me a lot.

Answer (score 7):

The keys are of type `interface{}`. Interface values in Go have two fields: the underlying value's type descriptor, and a pointer to the value itself. Two interface values with different underlying types are therefore not equal, even if the underlying values would be considered equal.